# AngularJS ui-router with templateProvider for A/B testing not rendering templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ab-testing

I have created an angular app where I would like to randomly render two different homepage view when a user accesses the url.

I have created the app.js file with the following code using templateProvider to inject the testService which carries a pick function to return random selection of two arguments. This is below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.service('testService', function(){
  function pick() {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arguments.length);
    return arguments[i];
  }
});


myApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateProvider: function(testService) {
      var result = testService.pick('a', 'b');
      return '<div ng-include="\'app/home-' + result + '.html\'"></div>';
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}])
```

My index.html is below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Get Penta</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

and my views 
home-a:

```
<div>Version A</div>
```

home-b:

```
<div>Version B</div>
```

However none of the templates are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

You can do this in several ways. I think your use of ng-include is failing, because basically this is done at page load time, and it's too late for that. I think a simple solution is to use the templateUrl, like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    templateUrl: function() {
      function pick(){
          var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arguments.length);
          return arguments[i];
      }
      var result = pick('a', 'b');
      return 'app/home-' + result + '.html';
    }
})
```

Comment: unfortunately you can't inject a service using templateUrl

Comment: True, but in this case the pick function is so small that you could just put it in the inline function

Comment: @sachin-karia I updated the answer - can you mark it as correct please?